# How to pass MySQL query data to JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, php

Here am getting data from mysql..

```
if (!empty($result1)) {
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $caseno = $row1['cases'];
        echo "<b>" . $caseno . "<br>";
    }
}
```

and i want pass the data which is there in `$caseno` to my below JavaScript..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaugevalue = document.getElementById("$caseno");
    var myConfig2 = {
        "type": "gauge",
        "scale-r": {
            "aperture": 200, //Scale Range
            "values": "0:50:10" //and minimum, maximum, and step scale values.
        },
        "series": [{"values": [gaugevalue]}]
            //"series":[{"values":[40]}]

    };

    zingchart.render({
        id: 'myChart',
        data: myConfig2,
        height: "90%",
        width: "90%"
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Victor for your replay, still it is not working..

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that you do not have an element with such an identifier. So, check my update.

Comment: The `gaugevalue`  must be an array of integers, not a single `$caseno`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Method:**

In your php code, you can do:

```
$caseno = $row1['cases'];
```

In your javascript code, you can do:

```
var gaugevalue = "<?php echo $caseno ?>";
```

**2nd Method:**

In your php code, you can do:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="caseno" value="'.$caseno.'">';
```

In your javascript code, you can do:

```
var gaugevalue = document.getElementById("caseno");
```

It's simple and easy.

Comment: Thanks Inzamam for your help.. i have modified according to your code, still not working..

Comment: you are coding in the same file or different? Please specify this also?

Answer (score 2):

I analyzed your code more attentively and noticed that `gaugevalue` must be an array of integers, while you are trying to pass to it a DOM element. So your full code should look like this:

```
<?php
$gauge_values = [];
if (!empty($result1)) {
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $gauge_values[] = $row1['cases'];
    }
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myConfig2 = {
        "type": "gauge",
        "scale-r": {
            "aperture": 200, //Scale Range
            "values": "0:50:10" //and minimum, maximum, and step scale values.
        },
        "series": [{"values": <?php echo json_encode($gauge_values); ?>}]
    };

    zingchart.render({
        id: 'myChart',
        data: myConfig2,
        height: "90%",
        width: "90%"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaugevalue = "<?php echo $caseno ?>";
    var gaugevalue = "<?= echo $caseno ?>"; //for shorthand
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

put you JavaScript in php:

```
<?php
echo "
<script type="text/javascript">
    var gaugevalue = document.getElementById("$caseno");
    var myConfig2 = {
    "type":"gauge",
    "scale-r":{
    "aperture":200, //Scale Range
    "values":"0:50:10" //and minimum, maximum, and step scale values.
    },
    "series":[{"values":[gaugevalue]}]
    //"series":[{"values":[40]}]

    };

    zingchart.render({ 
    id : 'myChart', 
    data : myConfig2, 
    height : "90%", 
    width: "90%"
    });

</script>
"
?>
```

You can pass your variable like this.

Comment: Thanks toykam, am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',

Comment: Escape the strings for it to work by changing the double qoutes in the JavaScript code.